# subertab vim plugin indent issue

Tags: vim, indentation, supertab

when I am at the beging of blank line. I am having issues with supertab plugin.It pops up completion window , while I am trying to indent a line like shown in the screen below.

[image]

any workaround please ?

Comment: https://github.com/ervandew/supertab#frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @romainl

The problem was caused by an old , unmaintained version of snipmate plugin.

so I installed [this](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) version instead.